# Make statement executable

Tags: shell, curl, command-line, terminal

I am new to writing scripts. I know how to make a script executable in terminal using chmod u+x . However I am looking for a way to make to make statements in the said script be run when that script is executed. For example my scrip1 file contains a statement, " sudo yum update" How do I write that statement in the script1 file so that when the script1 file is executed, the above statement is run.

Answer (score 1):

Shells evaluate code the same whether they're interactive or running a script.

If you want to run `sudo yum update` in a script, just write `sudo yum update` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not so clear but if you trying to execute one script from another you need to execute it with entry like ./other_script_name in the script which is calling it (provided your current pwd(working directory includes the second script)) or you can call it with its absolute path as argument to bash command like bash /path/to/otherscript/other_script_name